# Send Firebase notification with file PHP

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My file is the following:

```
<?php

ignore_user_abort();
ob_start();

 $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$Token = 'c128i0tYn..BA';

$fields = array('to' => $Token ,
'notification' => array('body' => 'HI', 'title' => ':)'));


define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'AIzaSyA9..4xU');

$headers = array(
      'Authorization:key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
      'Content-Type: application/json'
 );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false)
die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
?>
```

It work, perfectly but only for send notifications to a specific device(by the variable $Token).

Now I want to send notifications to all devices that have installed my app, 
What should I do? . Thanks!!

Comment: A typical solution is to have your [app subscribe to a specific topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) (e.g. `/topics/messages`) and then [send a message to that topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics).

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
'to' => $Token ,
```

For:

```
'registration_ids' => $ArrayOfTokens ,
```

reference 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream

Answer (score 0):

You can always send notification to a topic just make you notification format like:

```
{
   "to":"/topic/whatever-topic-you-want",
   "notification": {
                  "body":"I am the body",
                  "title":"I am title"
                   },
   "priority":"high"
}
```

and at the client side, if it's android device then just subscribe to the topic 'whatever-topic-you-want' using:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("whatever-topic-you-want");
```

and all of your device subscribed to that topic will receive the notification

[Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)